# How to allow my google script to be run by anyone off of a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, permissions

I am currently attempting to write a google script that will run once a submit button is clicked on a form in a webpage.  When the button is pressed it takes the form data, logs it into googles Logger and then emails a JSON report from the google account the script was made on.  I have just gotten this script to run and print how I want it to thanks to another user on this site and I have now run into the issue that the only reason it was running and working is because I was signed into google on the account I made to send the emails.  I have turned my script to public access by anyone on the web and still all I am getting is that google is "unable to open the page at this time." Is there some other way to get around this without having the user use their own email client?

```
var TO_ADDRESS = "test@email.com";
var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Confirmation');
function doPost(e) {
try{
Logger.log(e);
MailApp.sendEmail(T0_ADDRESS, "RFQ: The following person has requested a quote", JSON.stringify(e.parameters, null, 4));
return output;
```

This is the code which as I said earlier does work as long as I'm logged in but I would like this to be able to be used by anyone that accesses the website

Answer (score 2):

I have done something similar using "Deploy as web app" option you will get an url , you can give that to anyone and they too can execute this without any need of authorization.Below is a walkthrough

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can use this url in whatever way you like, as a curl request,ajax or just a browser url request
But note that you must have a `doGet()` otherwise it would give an error like in the final screenshot.But since i had put `doGet()` it ran perfectly (forgot to take its screen :P) .

Comment: Yep that fixed it! Thanks, I figured it had to be a small simple thing I was missing